# Babel errors in a Node.js app on Linux only

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, babeljs

I have deployed a Node.js app to an Amazon EC2 instance, using their Linux distro. It is a simple console app running through pm2 with the following structure:

```
package.json
start.js
index.js
config.js
.babelrc
src/
```

It is running on Node 10.14.1. `start.js` is the entry point of the application. This structure is zipped, SCP'd to the EC2 instance, unpacked, then I run an npm install and npm start.

When run on the EC2 instance, the following error appears in the logs:

```
SyntaxError: /home/ec2-user/Application/src/file.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (48:26):

  46 |     }
  47 | 
> 48 |     requestToStopUpdates = () => {
     |                          ^
```

This method is the first in its class.

The babel parts of my `package.json` look like this:

```
"@babel/core": "7.2.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.2.3",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "7.2.0",
"@babel/polyfill": "7.0.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "7.2.0",
"@babel/register": "7.0.0",
"babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
"babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
```

The app works perfectly fine when running on Windows. I have extracted the files to a different place on my PC and ran it with no issues, and even created a fresh Windows Server instance on EC2 and ran the app with no issues there.

Comment: What does your `npm start` do? I don't see anything that would run anything through Babel.

Comment: I can clearly see a closing curly brace before that function, what does it close?

Comment: npm start is: `"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production ENV=development node start.js",`. And the closing curly brace just closes the constructor above the method.